# Why do tendency tones and non-chord tones usually resolve down not up?

Tags: voice-leading

Not all the time but in voice leading the dissonances usually resolve down.. suspensions, leading tones, 7ths etc... they always are taught to resolve downwards. Why not up?

Comment: Dissonances are usually caused when one note is 'off key' by a semitone. It will depend which way takes that dissonance back to the consonance.

Comment: Wait, leading tones typically resolve down? I thought they typically resolve **up**.

Comment: @Dekkadeci I think we're using "leading tone" in the broader sense, in which in can be any non-chordal neighbor resolving by half step, not just ^7. Armani, I'm not sure the premise is true. Consider, in C major, a tritone of C with an F# above. The F# will resolve upward to G.

Comment: Ok maybe it is just my perception thus far... So not then tendency tones tend to resolve both ways? Why do suspensions always resolve down then?

Comment: Sus4 normally resolves down.  Sus2 might well resolve up.

Comment: In 16th-18th century species counterpoint (e.g, Fux), dissonances against the bass had to be prepared before and then resolved after, and they almost always resolved downward. There is no science to this, it is just a cultural tradition, similar to rules of etiquette or literary style. The notes don't "tend to" do anything on their own; they are moved around by people with distinct preferences.

Comment: @armani, re. suspension resolving downward, in my answer I basically say that many suspension resolutions are a FA to MI type resolution. Of course you need to allow for transposition. Temporarily treat the chord root of the resolution chord as DO, then you should see and hear the FA to MI movement. And if considering minor it's FA to ME.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you be conflating *tendency tones* and resolution of dissonance, especially suspensions.

A common definition of tendency tones is scale degrees of the subdominant and leading tone and their respective tendencies to resolve down to the mediant and up to the tonic. In that regard the upward and downward motions are equal.

Also, chromatic alterations are described has tendency tones, as in for example the augmented sixth chord, where the tendency tone resolves in the direction  of the chromatic alteration. So, the augmented sixth resolves up. But, it a chord like `V7/IV` the altered tone would be a *lowered* seventh scale degree and it would resolve *downward*. In both of those examples we can relate them back to the two "essential" tendency tones. The upward resolution of an augmented sixth is a leading tone motion and the downward resolution of a lowered seventh is like a subdominant to mediant motion.

By definition suspensions *always* resolve downward. If a suspended tone resolves upward, it is called *retardation*, which is a much less common resolution. You can also relate some suspensions back to tendency tones like when suspended sevenths or fourths resolve to a chordal third it is similar to the subdominant to mediant tendency motion.

I think the important distinction to make is *tendency tones* don't necessarily involve dissonance, but suspensions do. For example, when you have a progression like `V6 I` the leading tone tendency is the resolution upward to the tonic, but *no dissonances occur* in that progression.

If you mix tendency tones and suspension resolutions together, or especially only consider dissonant tendency tone progressions, I suppose the downward motions will seem more frequent. But, if you consider plain triadic descending fifth progressions from a dominant or secondary dominant involve tendency tone resolution, you will find upward tendency tone resolution very frequently.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's much to this premise by itself. It just so happens that the main *upwards*-resolving tone is the third of the dominant, which you would consider a consonance. Counterpoint generally eschews parallel motion, so as a consequence any other leading tones will tend to go downwards.

But this is by no means an absolute rule. The most obvious example of an upwards-resolving dissonance is the [augmented sixth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_sixth_chord).